# multiple ng-repeat only showing the first row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have problem with multiple `ng-repeat`, the second `ng-repeat` only showing value of first row. Here is the response of `http.get`

```
    [
      {
    "customerid": 
    "paydate": 
    "amount": 
    "acquirementid":
    "tracking_ref": 
    "billerdesc": 
    "productdesc": 
    "hpno": 
    "email": 
    "rc": 
    "rcdesc": 
    "lsadditonal": [
      {
    "label": " test ",
    "value": "",
    "required": "mandatory",
    "type": "text",
    "typeemail": null,
    "valuestruk": null
    }
]
    },
      {
    "customerid": "",
    "paydate": "",
    "amount": "",
    "acquirementid": "",
    "tracking_ref": "",
    "billerdesc": "",
    "productdesc": "",
    "hpno": "",
    "email": null,
    "rc": null,
    "rcdesc": null,
    "lsadditonal": [null],
    },
```

here is my html code

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <th>CustomerID</th>
                <th>Paydate</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>AcquirementID</th>
                <th>Tracking_ref</th>
                <th>BillerDesc</th>
                <th>ProductDesc</th>
                <th>HpNo</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Rc</th>
                <th>Rcesc</th>
                <th>Detail</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="item in coba">
                    <tr>
                    <td>{{item.customerid}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.paydate}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.amount}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.acquirementid}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.tracking_ref}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.billerdesc}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.productdesc}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.hpno}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.rc}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.rcdesc}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Lihat Detail Transaksi</button>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                         <div class="modal-content">
                         <div class="modal-header">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title">Detail </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Label</th>
                                    <th>Value</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody ng-repeat="item2 in item.lsadditonal">
                                <td>{{item2.label}}</td>
                                <td>{{item2.value}}</td>
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                <p>Total Rows : {{coba.length}}</p>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

The problem is, when I click button to show the modal. it's only showing data from first row. for example when I click the first row from, the data showing properly because in the first row there is data in lsadditional but when the second row clicked the modal showing value from the first row. in fact as you see in second row there is no data in lsadditional.

**note: lsadditional is the response that I want to show in modal**

Comment: Hi can you create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of the issue

Comment: i have try, but cant showing the modal. but i'l make with no modal it is ok?

Comment: The question is already answered. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are assigning same id to modal for every row to solve this attach row index with id

**Change**

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Lihat Detail Transaksi</button>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
```

**To**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_{{$index}}">Lihat Detail Transaksi</button>
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_{{$index}}" role="dialog">
```